# Control of Dynamixel MX28R via RS485

Tags: serial, raspberry-pi, uart, servo, rs485

I have problem controlling `dynamixel MX28R` servo motor.
I've tested two kinds of connection. First one to `raspberry Pi B+` and this is a
main use case. Here is my connection scheme.

[image: pix1: PIXMAP1]

Servo connects to `RS485 communication board`. `RSE` pin connects to `GPIO_0` of
raspberry. `RSE` needs to be set
to zero to receive and set to 1 for data transmission. I have modified C++ SDK
and add turning GPIO_0 on before writing and off after.
from `DynamixelSDK/c++/src/dynamixel_sdk_linux/port_handler_linux.cpp`

```
#define RES_PIN 0
...
PortHandlerLinux::PortHandlerLinux(const char *port_name)
  : socket_fd_(-1),
    baudrate_(DEFAULT_BAUDRATE_),
    packet_start_time_(0.0),
    packet_timeout_(0.0),
    tx_time_per_byte(0.0)
{
  is_using_ = false;
  setPortName(port_name);
  wiringPiSetup () ; //           <<<< this is my code
  pinMode (RES_PIN, OUTPUT); //   <<<<
  digitalWrite (RES_PIN, LOW); // <<<<
}
...

int PortHandlerLinux::writePort(uint8_t *packet, int length)
{
  digitalWrite (RES_PIN, HIGH); //<<<<
  // delay1 don't work with or without delays
  int res = write(socket_fd_, packet, length);
  // delay2
  digitalWrite (RES_PIN, LOW); // <<<<
  return res;
}

...
```

But when I run examples
I see `There is no status packet!` error. And motor doesn't reacts. I've tried to send
commands through `dxl_monitor`. For example to turn on LED: `w1 1 25 1` or
`w1 255 25 1` but nothing happens. Also I've tried to send raw [instruction packet](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/communication/dxl_packet.htm) from [this example](http://www.oppedijk.com/robotics/control-dynamixel-with-raspberrypi).

```
import serial
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(0, GPIO.OUT)

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=1000000, timeout=3.0)

while True:
        GPIO.output(0, GPIO.HIGH)
        port.write(bytearray.fromhex("FF FF 01 05 03 1E 32 03 A3"))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(0, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(3)

        GPIO.output(0,GPIO.HIGH)
        port.write(bytearray.fromhex("FF FF 01 05 03 1E CD 00 0b"))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.output(0,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(3)
```

I've also tried to change baudrate to different values from
this [manual](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-28.htm) with no result.

Here is another connection that I've used.

[image: pix2]

`RSE` pin always set to 1 for transmit data from PC.

I sent raw instruction packets with the same python code (without `GPIO` stuff).
But servo does not react.

Also I've noticed that led on `UART` turns on for a while, when I turn on dynamixel.
Like it sends some data on power on. I've tried to read data with screen utile:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 1000000 cs8
```

Tested with different baud-rates but screen shows no info.

Answer (score 1):

This certainly won't work:

```
int res = write(socket_fd_, packet, length);
// delay2
digitalWrite (RES_PIN, LOW); // <<<<
```

The reason is that write() is asynchronous, and just puts bytes into the outgoing serial port buffer; it does not wait for the data to finish sending.
You can use tcgetattr() followed by tcsetattr() with TCSADRAIN to make sure the output buffer gets fully flushed before you switch direction back.

```
#include <termios.h>

// call this after you've called write() for the data,
// before you attempt to switch direction again.
struct termios tio;
tcgetattr(fd, &tio);
tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &tio);
```

Other than that, what does the oscilloscope or logic probe say about the three wires you're supposed to be changing from the Pi? (RX, TX, and DIR)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the `write()` function. I don't have an osciloscope, and can only be sure that some data transmits and no data comes back.